# How to delay Bootstrap 3 carousel using setTimeout?

Tags: bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel, delay

I have various (9!) carousels in one page, and would like them to start at different timing... how is this possible? setTimeout function? could someone please show me how? Here's my code so far:

**HTML**

```
<div id="carouselOne" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="img/grid/1b.png" class="grayscale">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="img/grid/1a.png" class="grayscale">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$("#carouselOne").carousel({
  interval: 5000,
});
```

Comment: if you set different `interval` values to each carousel does not that fulfill the  `delay` purpose?

Comment: Hi! That would work, but I want all the carousels to have the same interval between images... Only starting at different timing. Thanks @byoigres for trying to help.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a delay option to the bootstrap `carousel.DEFAULTS`. Via `$.fn.carousel.Constructor` you have access to the carousel constructor function.

> [Programmatic API](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#js-programmatic-api)
>
> Each plugin also exposes its raw constructor on a Constructor property: `$.fn.popover.Constructor`. If you'd like to get a particular plugin instance, retrieve it directly from an element: `$('[rel="popover"]').data('popover')`.

So you could add a custom method to the carousel constructor prototype, which will fire the `cycle` method within a `setTimeout` defined by the `delay` option. You can add the delay as a data attribute to your carousel elements, just like you would add any other data attribute e.g.
`<div ... data-delay="3000" ...>`

Here is a quick example.

```js
var customCarousel = $.fn.carousel.Constructor,
    $carousels = $('.carousel');
// Set the pause option which defaults to "hover" to false,
// because this will mess up the delay and looks ugly.
customCarousel.DEFAULTS.pause = "false";
// Add delay option to the defaults of carousel.
customCarousel.DEFAULTS.delay = 0;
// Add a custom delay method to the carousel prototype.
customCarousel.prototype.delay = function(e) {
  var that = this;
  // Pause all instances.
  this.pause();
  // Call setTimout with the value set in data-delay attribute.
  // Be aware this will be added on to the data-interval!
  // So an interval of 3000 with a delay of 1000 will start the
  // carousel after 4 seconds.
  setTimeout(function(that) {
    that.cycle();
  }, this.options.delay, that)

}
// Call the carousels with the delay method.
$carousels.carousel('delay');
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div id="carouselOne" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="3000" data-delay="1000">
        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
          <div class="item active">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x200/1abc9c/ffffff?text=image-one" class="grayscale">
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x200/f1c40f/ffffff?text=image-two" class="grayscale">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div id="carouselTwo" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="3000" data-delay="2000">
        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
          <div class="item active">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x200/3498db/ffffff?text=image-one" class="grayscale">
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x200/e74c3c/ffffff?text=image-two" class="grayscale">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div id="carouselThree" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="3000" data-delay="3000">
        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
          <div class="item active">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x200/9b59b6/ffffff?text=image-one" class="grayscale">
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x200/34495e/ffffff?text=image-two" class="grayscale">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi @DavidDomain. I'm very pleased, it's working! Thanks lots for solving my problem. Here's a [link](http://mariagill.co.uk/index2.html) for the page. I'm now trying to get them (the carousels) triggered as soon as the page loads, without having to wait the interval to run... Any ideas? I'm aware that you doing me a big favour (and I'm super grateful) and that you don't have any obligations to help me again! Cheers.

Comment: I shortened the delays (and also the intervals) and it looks much better! So there's no more need to launch the carousels before the interval runs first... Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up have the same problem as you are. Here is what I did:

```
function start_carousel_0(){
    $('#logosCarousel_0').carousel({
         interval : 10000
    });
}
function start_carousel_1(){
    $('#logosCarousel_1').carousel({
         interval : 10000
    });
}
// setTimeout functions

setTimeout(start_carousel_0, 1000);
setTimeout(start_carousel_1, 5000);
```

I wrote different functions for each carousel. The second carousel will start at a different time than the first one. It works in my case.

Answer (score 0):

@daviddomain's answer can be adapted to Bootstrap 4 (I'm using version 4.6)

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  var customCarousel = $.fn.carousel.Constructor,
    $carousels = $('.carousel');
  customCarousel.Default.pause = "false";
  customCarousel.Default.delay = 0;
  customCarousel.prototype.delay = function (e) {
    var that = this;
    this.pause()
    setTimeout(function (that) {
      that.cycle()
    }, this._config.delay, that)
  }
  $carousels.carousel('delay')
}, false)
```

We need to change `DEFAULTS` into `Default` and `options` into `_config`.